# Access VBA set focus to search field in form record control when form is opened

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do i set focus to  [image: access record controls - search field]

I am trying to set focus to the search box in a form's record controls when a form is opened or becomes active again. Can't find reference the name of the object.

Comment: Form in datasheet mode has very few features for customization and control, I'm afraid without API calls it won't be possible. You will need to scan all controls in window, find handler of search control and move focus there. I have examples for searching scroll bar controls on any window, it can be done the same way.

Comment: BTW, you can switch to row number field using Alt-F5 key and then switch to Search field using Tab, but number of tabs depens on current position and filter, so it should be calculeted before using `Sendkey` function. This is not good, but working solution